# Stringification macro always adds a single space character

Tags: c, gcc, macros, stringification

Given the following code that prints a string which is a stringification of two words:

```
#define PORT_INFO_MAC_2(portNum)   port:     portNum

#define PORT_INFO_MAC(portNum) PORT_INFO_MAC_2(portNum)

/* Stringify macro expansion instead of the macro itself */
#define INVOKE_MACRO(...) #__VA_ARGS__

printf(" %s " , INVOKE_MACRO(PORT_INFO_MAC(1)) ); /* In a more general way, I'll be using it like follows: INVOKE_MACRO(PORT_INFO_MAC(2), PORT_INFO_MAC(1), ...) */
```

The output is always `" port: 1 "` with a single space between the `"port"` and the `"1"`. Why is there always a single space there and is there a way to control the amount of spaces?

changing the amount of spaces in `PORT_INFO_MAC_2` macro between `port` and `portNum` doesn't change the output space amount.

**EDIT**
It seems that there are two cases, at the fist case the `port` and `portNum` are closest- `PORT_INFO_MAC_2(portNum)   port:portNum` which then no space exist in the output between them. At the second case, in which any number of spaces exist in the macro between them, the amount of spaces in the output is always 1.
Is there any formal explanation for that? Is there any control over that?

Comment: Note: "spacebar" is the large button on you keyboard which generates _space_ characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is there always a single space there and is there a way to control the amount of spaces?

Because that's what the stringification operator is specified to do:

> If,  in  the  replacement  list,  a  parameter  is  immediately  preceded  by a `#` preprocessing token,  both  are  replaced  by  a  single  character  string  literal  preprocessing  token  that contains   the  spelling   of   the   preprocessing   token   sequence   for   the   corresponding argument.  **Each occurrence of white space between the argument’s preprocessing tokens becomes  a  single  space  character  in  the  character  string  literal.**

(C2011 6.10.3.2/2; emphasis added)

Of course, if there is no whitespace at all between the preprocessing tokens, then none appears in the stringification.

Comment: Spot on. Can you provide a link to the source document?

Comment: @user2162550, I generally refer to [a PDF version of the N1570 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).  My answer contains the section and paragraph numbers.  You can find other versions, including HTML renditions, by Googling for "n1570".  The final standard document is not available for free, but it has only trivial differences from N1570.